# How to register and get multiple DbContexts of the same type?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

So imagine you want to access the multiple dbContexts that are on different environments or servers (Dev, Test, Pre-prod etc), and use the data from all those different databases to calculate something. How would I register multiple dbContexts of the same type (`MonitoringDbContext`) and differentiate between them?

This is where I got stuck

```
var envDbContextDetails = configuration.GetSection("EnvironmentConnectionStrings").Get<EnvironmentConnectionStringsModel>();

var nonRegisteredDbContexts = envDbContextDetails.DbConnectionStrings.Where(x => x.Environment != envDbContextDetails.CurrentDbEnvironment).ToList();            

nonRegisteredDbContexts.ForEach(x => services.AddDbContext<MonitoringDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(x.ConnectionString)));
```

So I'm registering multiple `MonitoringDbContext` contexts, and now what? My idea was to resolve, pull them and add them in a `Dictionary<string, MonitoringDbContext>` where the key is the environment name (Dev, Test etc) and use them from a `DbContextFactory` where I would select the one I need, or use all of them in a loop, depending on what I need to calculate. But I have no idea how to get the dbContexts after registering them, and how to differentiate between them.

Comment: The question is unclear. You don't need multiple DbContexts to connect to different databases. You only need a different connection string. Is your application going to connect to production, staging and development databases *at the same time*? If not, you can pick the correct connection string before calling `AddDbContext` from configuration and use it. In fact, that's how things already work if you store the connection string in appsettings.json

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the app should connect to production, staging and development databases at the same time. So imagine you want aggregate data from staging, dev and production - you need to connect to all databases at the same time, gather and calculate the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register multiple instances of a service in the services collection, and get all of them by resolving `IEnumerable<T>` where T is the type of your service.

Knowing that, you should inspect the code of your library and check if registration of services do simple `Add` in the `IServiceCollection`. EF Core use TryAddX, so just your first registration is included in the service collection. So we have to customize the registration.

You can create a wrapper like that:

```cs
public class EnvWrapper<T>
{
    public string Env { get; }
    public T Value { get; }

    public EnvWrapper(string env, T value)
    {
        Env = env;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Then register the basics services EF Core needs to run:

```cs
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();
```

Then foreach environment, register an EnvWrapper with an instance of your DbContext:

```cs
var connectionStringsByEnv = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    ["dev"] = "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=tests;Integrated Security=True;",
    ["prd"] = "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=tests;Integrated Security=True;"
};

var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();

foreach (var cs in connectionStringsByEnv)
{
    var dbContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MonitoringDbContext>()
            .UseSqlServer(cs.Value)
            .Options;

    services.AddScoped(_ =>
    {
        return new EnvWrapper<MonitoringDbContext>(cs.Key, new MonitoringDbContext(dbContextOptions));
    });
}
```

If you want, you can resolve `IEnumerable<Wrapper<MonitoringDbContext>>` and iterate on the result:

```cs
public class MonitoringDbContextStore : IReadOnlyDictionary<string, MonitoringDbContext>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, MonitoringDbContext> _contexts;

    public MonitoringDbContextStore(IEnumerable<EnvWrapper<MonitoringDbContext>> contexts)
    {
        _contexts = contexts.ToDictionary(c => c.Env, c => c.Value/*, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase*/);
    }
}
```

Maybe you should register `MonitoringDbContextStore` in your service collection.

If you want/need `IDbContextFactory`, you can add more services:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IDbContextFactorySource<MonitoringDbContext>, DbContextFactorySource<MonitoringDbContext>>();
```

And per environment:

```cs
services.AddScoped(sp =>
{
    var factorySource = sp.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactorySource<MonitoringDbContext>>();
    return new EnvWrapper<IDbContextFactory<MonitoringDbContext>>(cs.Key, new DbContextFactory<MonitoringDbContext>(sp, dbContextOptions, factorySource));
});
```

Again, you can resolve a collection of EnvWrapper with the type `IEnumerable<EnvWrapper<IDbContextFactory<MonitoringDbContext>>>`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually applications should be environment agnostic, being different environments just different instances of the same application, but that's clearly not your case.

You could have child classes of your `MonitoringDbContext`, that passes through the constructor which connection string is to be used. That way you can have one instance for each environment in a more declarative way.

If you don't have a fixed number of environments that can be known at compile time, you would have to implement some kind of Factory yourself. Such structure would hold or return an instance for every environment that you have. Note that you would have to inject that Factory into your classes, rather than injecting the `MonitoringDbContext` directly.

Comment: somehow this ends up getting the two equal contexts with same connection string but different types